# How can I use adb in Meta Quest3 to get the screen of the device, but I want this screen to be available and processed by me

Tags: android, adb, virtual-reality, oculusquest

How can I use adb in Meta Quest 3 to get the device's screen, like Meta Quest Casting, but I want this screen to be available and processed by me?

I tried Scrcpy but it doesn't work as well as it should, he has two screens, both irregularly shaped, and the angle is still crooked

[Scrcpy image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siJ50.jpg)

I'm sure it can be done, as I've seen the same feature on some other unofficial software

Why don't I just use Meta Quest Casting, because I want to get every frame in real time and put it into my program, and I have to do some processing

New addendum: I think the similar casting feature of the commercial software I know of is done by using a new software in the machine to record the screen, not entirely via adb, then the fact that I don't need to go through adb, it's just that I want to get the screen and process it, and that's enough!

Comment: Related: https://communityforums.atmeta.com/t5/Get-Help/Primary-accounts-can-not-cast-to-Chromecast-devices/m-p/1130960/highlight/true#M260366

Comment: A branch in scrcpy to apply rotation/scaling for MetaQuest 3: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/pull/4658